# two sets of physical IO metrics in Oracle's v$sysmetric?why?

Tags: oracle, io, metrics

I found two sets of physical IO metrics in v$sysmetric: one has "Total" in the metric name while the other does not (e.g., "Physical Read **Total** IO Requests Per Sec" vs "Physical Read IO Requests Per Sec"). Does anyone know what is the difference? Thanks a lot in advance.

The Oracle DB I am using: 11.2.0.3.0 64bit, two nodes RAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Oracle 12c Database Reference Statistics Descriptions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2FBC1B7E-9123-41DD-8178-96176260A639.htm#REFRN-GUID-2FBC1B7E-9123-41DD-8178-96176260A639),
the difference is the "total" metric includes system activity like backups and recovery, the other metric does not.

> **physical read IO requests**
>
> Number of read requests for application activity (mainly buffer cache
>   and direct load operation) which read one or more database blocks per
>   request. This is a subset of "physical read total IO requests"
>   statistic.
>
> **physical read total IO requests**
>
> Number of read requests which read one or more database blocks for all
>   instance activity including application, backup and recovery, and
>   other utilities. The difference between this value and "physical read
>   total multi block requests" gives the total number of single block
>   read requests.